# How to make distinction between user establishing another connection and different user, under same network, establishing new connection

Tags: node.js, websockets

Sorry, the title of my question might be a little confusing. I have this online game that utilizes websocket connections for the users to initialize so my server can broadcast messages to all them in real-time as the game progresses. I figured this was a better solution than having the clients polling the server every X amount of seconds asking for updates.

I recently came to the stunning (to me at least) revelation that clients that are connected to the same household network **share the same public IP address.** I have some server logic that enforces every websocket connection to have a unique IP address. So as you can see, this sorta screws up that logic. I added this check in mostly because I didn't want users being able to be in multiple games at once.

I *can* bypass this check and allow all websocket connections, even if they share the IP address of an already connected client, but I'm wondering if there'd be anywhere I could determine whether the **same user** is simply opening up a new tab to try and join another game, or if a **completely different user under the same household network as the first user** is trying to establish a new connection to join their **first** game.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502631/how-to-make-distinction-between-user-establishing-another-connection-and-differe "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: What if one person has two computers?

Answer (score 0):

As Bart noted, requiring each user to login separately is a possibility.

However, that doesn't prevent users from creating multiple accounts and playing them in parallel (called multiboxing in some games). In the extreme, they might use a different device with a different browser to avoid detection, and it's only one additional step to use a different IP address through mobile data or a VPN.

This means that you cannot reliably detect whether one person using multiple identities or multiple persons are using your game. Indicators such as same-ip may be used to raise flags but shouldn't prevent people in the same household from playing. How much effort you want to put into this depends on how severely your game is affected by multiboxing.

Answer (score -1):

> determine whether the same user is simply opening up a new tab to try and join another game, or if a completely different user under the same household network as the first user is trying to establish a new connection to join their first game.

The only way to reliably differentiate between different users on the same private (household) network is to require each user to login to your server. When each user has a unique username or id, then you can use that to determine if they try to open two games at the same time and you can even tell that if they are doing so from different machines.